# Why doesn't navigation work for me after calling Navigation.InsertPageBefore() in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to implement logging in on Xamarin Forms (5.0.0, using ActiveDirectory's built in Login page).  Any ideas on how to make this work?

In the constructor of App.xaml.cs, I have:

```cs
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
        }
```

I implement the Login page w/ a view model, in which I pass in a callback that should (according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#manipulating-the-navigation-stack)), set my navigation root to my HomePage:

```cs
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        private async Task _handleLoginAsync()
        {
            Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new HomePage(), this);
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
        }

        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new LoginPageViewModel(_handleLoginAsync);
        }

    }
```

In the view model, I try to login using Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread, calling my(note, I didn't include login logic for brevity/cleanliness)

```cs
        public Command LoginCommand => new Command(LoginUsingAzureAsync);
        private Func<Task>_handleLoginAsync;

        public LoginPageViewModel(Func<Task> handleLoginAsync)
        {
            _handleLoginAsync = handleLoginAsync;
            LoginCommand.Execute(null);
        }

        internal void LoginUsingAzureAsync()
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    if (await Login()) == true)
                    {
                        UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
                        await _handleLoginAsync();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

                    UserDialogs.Instance.Alert("The login has failed.");
                }
            });
         }
```

It successfully goes to the homepage, but navigating to other pages afterwards doesn't work.  When I call the following, it enters the `OtherPage()` constructor, but fails to render the new page.

```cs
   Navigation.PushAsync(new OtherPage());
```

Note, the navigation works as expected if I use `PushAsync(new HomePage())` rather than removing the login, but I'd prefer to remove the login page from the navigation stack.

Thanks in advance!

---

Update:  Here's the initial HomeViewModel:

```cs
    public class HomeViewModel
    {
        private readonly INavigation _navigation;

        public Command GoToOtherPageCommand => new Command(GoToOtherPage);

        public async void GoToOtherPage()
        {
            await App.Navigation.PushAsync(new OtherPage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: it's fairly common to just reassign MainPage after login to prevent your LoginPage from remaining in the nav stack.  That may be a simpler approach than what you're doing

Comment: Thanks Jason, but I had tried that, and it still breaks navigation from my HomePage.

Comment: have you tried just using the Navigation reference on the page instead of App.Navigation?

Comment: Please check [this sample proj](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/817221c0fa7ba8a4f874b842d352217885d6ae5d/Navigation/LoginFlow/LoginNavigation). From [this Login class](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/817221c0fa7ba8a4f874b842d352217885d6ae5d/Navigation/LoginFlow/LoginNavigation/LoginPage.xaml.cs#L28) InsertBefore seems good, but notice how the MainPage was defined in [App.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/817221c0fa7ba8a4f874b842d352217885d6ae5d/Navigation/LoginFlow/LoginNavigation/App.cs#L14).

Comment: Plus, since you're using XF5.0, would recommend [XF Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/) then.

Comment: I'll take a look at XF shell.  The app I'm currently working on was started before XF 5, so I'm not sure how much work it would be to switch over.  I'll definitely look into it for future projects though.

I figured out my problem, the HomePage was directly referencing App.Navigation.  I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't in the login, it was in the HomePageViewModel, which was initially referencing App.Navigation (see update in question).

Passing in the navigation into my ViewModel did the trick:

```cs
    public class HomeViewModel
    {
        private readonly INavigation _navigation;

        public Command GoToOtherPageCommand => new Command(GoToOtherPage);

        public async void GoToOtherPage()
        {
            await _navigation.PushAsync(new OtherPage());
        }

        public HomeViewModel(INavigation navigation)
        {
            _navigation = navigation;
        }
    }
```

```cs
    public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
    {
        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new HomeViewModel(Navigation);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In what way does it break MVVM?  Do you have any suggestions on how to improve it?  Maybe declaring GoToOtherPage in the code behind and passing it into the ViewModel as a callback?  That could make it relatively easy to mock.

Comment: In MVVM  VM is not supposed to do the navigation thing, one way to do is using MessagingCenter, here is [a long forum discussion](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21822/call-navigation-pushasync-from-viewmodel)